# /usr/bin/python: No module named pip when using pip with python2

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, python-2.x

I am following the installation guide for the Tensorflow Object Detection API, which determines the following:

//From within TensorFlow/models/research/ cp object_detection/packages/tf2/setup.py . python -m pip install --use-feature=2020-resolver .

When I run the second command, I the error:

/usr/bin/python: No module named pip

I have pip3 installed, as well as python2 and python3. What are my options here? Install a custom outdated pip file, which could possibly conflict with pip3?

Link to the tutorial: https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#tensorflow-object-detection-api-installation

Tried installing python-pip from command line, it points to the pip3 package, so I need to find a way to use the old pip package, without breaking the newer pip one.

Comment: Why do you want to use Python 2?

Comment: If you had pip installed properly, `python -m pip` wouldn't give you that error. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+No+module+named+pip

Comment: I want to use python2 because the tutorial uses python2.

Comment: Do not use python2, it is end of life,  prefer a tutorial that is not outdated.

Comment: There are very few tutorials on this subject. Most do not go in depth to it - I struggled to find an installation guide for this API.

Comment: The tutorial you linked uses _Tensorflow 2_ which is not the same as Python 2. It clearly states to use Python 3. Your `python` command may be linked with your Python 2 installation. Try `python3` instead.